# Im trying to reduplicate the shelljs exec type execution in node

Tags: node.js, exec, shelljs

I was using shelljs before where i used to call a command like so:

```
require('shelljs/global');

let res = exec('echo hello').stdout
```

But I would like to achieve this in node without relying on shelljs.
Thing is I've found examples with node and I'm having trouble with quite a few of them.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultra simple answer is use the [synchronous](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_synchronous_process_creation) version of [exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options). The stdout won't appear as the command runs and the result won't have the nice properties shelljs provides, just the `stdout` data

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process')
const exec = (cmd) => execSync(cmd).toString()
const res = exec('echo "hello there"')
```

The full shelljs implementation is in [exec.js](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs/blob/master/src/exec.js), which runs the command via [`exec-child.js`](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs/blob/master/src/exec-child.js) script to enable the live output + capture to variables for a synchronous exec. It depends on the features you require as to how complex the solution becomes.